# Dealing with time drift: How to take a timestamp sent by the server and make a client side adjustment for a client time that is different

Tags: jquery, timer, websocket, ratchet

We're working on Symfony / Doctrine with WebSockets (Ratchet) to display an auction timer. We are using a unix epoch timestamp that gets converted to create a JavaScript Date() object (basically epoch * 1000).

**Issue with drift on client**: Even if I set the current serverside timestamp at the absolute last moment the process that in the WebSocket event clientside, there is still a potential for drift that can’t be accounted for in how long it takes to get the response from server to client. If I do `new Date()` in JS and `time()` in PHP at the exact same moment, that would give an accurate measurement of how much drift there is between server and client… any time it takes between running `time()` and `new Date()` adds to the potential drift and causes possible inaccuracies. So, if it ever took one or two seconds for a client to get the update, then the math would still be off that one to two seconds.

The WebSocket events don’t generate response headers with timestamps or anything like that either, so there’s no “known” value to base off of saying “this is the exact moment the server sent the response”.

For reference, some timers are off by 2 or more seconds.

**My only solution**: The best I can do is include the response of `time()` in the WebSocket events and process that, but it will NEVER be 100% accurate without devising a way to create a countdown system that says “count exactly X milliseconds from start” and not having it do any form of calculation whatsoever based on the client time.

Any ideas on how to eliminate this drift and get the most accurate timer across multiple machines via WebSockets?

Comment: Have you considered using UTC time? If you standardize the clock both on server and client, in theory, you can now time anything with date arithmetic?

Comment: Adding to @MacPrawn, instead of sending to the client how much time is remaining, send the UTC timestamp that the auction ends. Then you can use the client's `+new Date()` and compare that with the timestamp.

Comment: The time stamp is already a UTC time, just Unix Epoch versus a pretty date.

The countdown counts based on the diff with that end time and `new Date()` at each interval (something like 100ms, it's basically constant).

To calculate diff you have to send a timestamp with the request and compare that to `new Date()` to somewhat extrapolate the difference.  It'll still be skewed based on how long it takes the response to get there and by the fact PHP uses full seconds for its time functions and JavaScript uses milliseconds.